# Rails 4 search Multiple Params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm looking to search and find results if two params exist, but i'm getting sent to car_show_path, but should have results.

Model

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.search(car_number, car_model) 
    where(['car_number = ? AND car_model = ?', "%#{car_number}%", "%#{car_model}%"])
  end
end
```

Controller Show

```
 @search = Car.search(params[:car_number], params[:car_model])
   if @search.present?
       @search
    else
     redirect_to car_path, notice: "Not a valid combination"
    end
```

Form

```
<%= simple_form_for :search, url: car_show_path do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :car_number, :collection => @car.collect {|c| [c.number]}, :include_blank => false %>
  <%= f.input :car_model, placeholder: "Car Model" %>
  <%= f.button :submit, 'Generate', class: 'btn' %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are doing it wrong. If you look into the params hash generated in the server log, you can see something like this `:search => {:car_model => "value", :car_number => "Value"}`. That means the values of `:car_model` and `:car_number` cannot be retrieved with `params[:car_model]` and `params[:car_number]`, instead you should use `params[:search][:car_model]` and `params[:search][:car_number]`

```
@search = Car.search(params[:search][:car_number], params[:search][:car_model])
if @search.present?
  @search
else
  redirect_to car_path, notice: "Not a valid combination"
end
```

Comment: I was able to view the car_model entry in the server log, but the collection car_number isn't being picked up. The drop down selection work fine, but it isn't being passed through. @car = Car.group(:car_number) is the variable.

Comment: @DollarChills can you post the server log here?

Comment: Processing by CarController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"CzlNZlINufrHVGrkW9GLvZqiRWBtD2mplrlFuSMTKIEZ1fe5lK1UdEey1KlFSa0IOHgp0c2Po5GgkyZkgPbkOA==", "search"=>{"car_number"=>"", "car_model"=>"Toyota"}, "commit"=>"Generate"}
  Auslot Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `cars`.* FROM `cars` WHERE ( car_number = '' AND car_model = 'Toyota')
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/cars
Completed 302 Found in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)

Comment: I think collection select works differently in rails 4, could be wrong.

Comment: @DollarChills Try changing `<%= f.input :car_number, :collection => @car.collect {|c| [c.number]}, :include_blank => false %>` to `<%= f.input :car_number, :collection => @car, :include_blank => false %>`

Comment: I have resolved this. I removed the brackets around [c.number] in my collection and it worked. I shall give the answer to @Pavan as he helped me out with the major issues. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

I see the code you have provided. I believe the code you have written need some improvement. So I have re-written code which may solve your issue and bring to your goal. Here it is :

```
#/app/models/car.rb

class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.search(cn, cm) 
    where('car_number = ? AND car_model = ?', cn, cm)
  end
end

#/app/controllers/cars_controller.rb

class CarsController < ApplicationController

  def search
    @result = Car.search params[c_number], params[c_modal]
  end
end


#/app/views/cars/search.html.erb
#you can generate similar form with simple_form_for

<form action="/search" method="/get" >
  <input type="text" name="c_number"
  <input type="text" name="c_modal">
  <input type="submit" value="search">
</form>

<% if !@result.any? %>
  Not a valid combination
<% end %>

<% @result.each do |r|%>
  <%= r.car_number %>
  <%= r.car_modal %>
<% end %>


#/config/routes.rb

get "/search" => "cars#search"
```

Note : Above code is best of my practice and didn't executed locally.

Hope that helps!!!

Answer (score -1):

You are putting the same values into both placeholders from the query parameter that is being sent to your search method. That doesn't seem right.